# Subdivide nested dictionary, while applying percentage from values in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to subdivide a dictionary, while applying the values (which are percentages, to the value of another.

I have those sets of data:

```
{'C-STD-B&M-SUM': {datetime.date(2015, 5, 20): 0.21484699999999998,
               datetime.date(2015, 5, 21): 0.245074,
               datetime.date(2015, 5, 22): 0.27874}

{'G-CAM-BAC-SUM': {datetime.date(2015, 5, 20): 0.13294399999999998,
               datetime.date(2015, 5, 21): 0.151648,
               datetime.date(2015, 5, 22): 0.17248,
               datetime.date(2015, 5, 23): 0.195664}

{'G-CAM-BAC-XS': 0.06, 'G-CAM-BAC-XXS': 0.01, 'G-CAM-BAC-XL': 0.11, 'G-CAM-BAC-S': 0.19, 'G-CAM-BAC-L': 0.26, 'G-CAM-BAC-XXL': 0.03, 'G-CAM-BAC-M': 0.35}

{'C-STD-B&M-XL': 0.3, 'C-STD-B&M-XXL': 0.11, 'C-STD-B&M-S': 0.06, 'C-STD-B&M-M': 0.2, 'C-STD-B&M-XS': 0, 'C-STD-B&M-L': 0.32}
```

Expected output:

```
{'C-STD-B&M-XL': {datetime.date(2015, 5, 20): 0.21484699999999998*0.3,
           datetime.date(2015, 5, 21): 0.245074*0.3,
           datetime.date(2015, 5, 22): 0.27874*0.3}

{'C-STD-B&M-XXS': {datetime.date(2015, 5, 20): 0.21484699999999998*0.1,
           datetime.date(2015, 5, 21): 0.245074*0.1,
           datetime.date(2015, 5, 22): 0.27874*0.1}

{'C-STD-B&M-XXL': {datetime.date(2015, 5, 20): 0.21484699999999998*0.11,
           datetime.date(2015, 5, 21): 0.245074*0.11,
           datetime.date(2015, 5, 22): 0.27874*0.11}
```

And so on, for all the dictionaries. Note that I need the result of the multiplications on the values, not the statement, just left them on to make it clearer.

My code so far (partial):

```
def apply_size_distribution(dictionary_with_temporal_distribution):
    gown_cap_size = get_size_distribution('G2:G7', 'H2:H7')
    cap_medium_demand = gown_cap_size['C-STD-B&M-M']
    for k, v in dictionary_with_temporal_distribution.items():
        if k == "C-STD-B&M-SUM":
            dictionary_with_temporal_distribution['C-STD-B&M-M'] = dictionary_with_temporal_distribution.pop('C-STD-B&M-SUM')
            for k, v in dictionary_with_temporal_distribution['C-STD-B&M-M'].items():
                dictionary_with_temporal_distribution["{}".format(k)] = v * cap_medium_demand
```

But I'm getting the good old dictionary changed during iteration. Also, using my code I'll have to copy and paste the code for each size, changing only the name of the Key to the appropriate size. I was wondering if there is a more robust method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the `dictionary_with_temporal_distribution` changed because in your code you are changing it -

```
dictionary_with_temporal_distribution["{}".format(k)] = v * cap_medium_demand
```

Instead you should consider creating a new dictionary at the start and maybe add elements to it as you continue processing and at the end return it.

Also, instead of hard coding the values like you did - `gown_cap_size['C-STD-B&M-M']` - `k == "C-STD-B&M-SUM"` , you should use `string.rsplit('-', 1)[0]` to find out the common part - `C-STD-B&M` and then use that for equality.

Your code would look something like -

```
def apply_size_distribution(dictionary_with_temporal_distribution):
    gown_cap_size = get_size_distribution('G2:G7', 'H2:H7')
    retlist = {}
    for cap_demand in grown_cap_size:
        for k, v in dictionary_with_temporal_distribution.items():
            if k.rsplit('-', 1)[0] == cap_demand.rsplit('-', 1)[0]:
                if cap_demand not in retlist:
                    retlist[cap_demand] = {}
                temp = retlist[cap_demand]
                for k1, v1 in dictionary_with_temporal_distribution[k].items():
                    temp[k1] = v1 * grown_cap_size[cap_demand]
    return retlist
```

Comment: Edit : Added the returning retlist part.